# Swing Zoom Application

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to design a zoom application which zooms the region of rectangle which is surrounding mouse pointer...

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package zoom;

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author keyur Parekh
 */
public class Zoom extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    Robot r;
    Window wnd;
    int width, height;

    /**
     */
    public Zoom() {
        try {
            r = new Robot();
            Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            width = (int) d.getWidth();
            height = (int) d.getHeight();
            System.out.println(width + " " + height);
            wnd = new Window(this);
            wnd.setSize(400, 400);
            wnd.setLocation(0, 0);
            wnd.setVisible(true);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        Thread t = new Thread();
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Zoom();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {            
            PointerInfo pi = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            Point p = pi.getLocation();
            int x = (int) p.getX();
            int y = (int) p.getY();

            Graphics g = wnd.getGraphics();
            Rectangle rect =  new Rectangle(x, y, 150, 150);
            BufferedImage img = r.createScreenCapture(rect);
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 250, 250, Color.white, this);
        }
    }

}
```

In this the output is not coming as it is supposed to, the window is opening properly but when I hover my mouse over it, it is just not zooming up....
[image]
As this image is printscreen it is not showing mouse pointer but it is on the window only.

So can somebody please help me out.

Comment: what are you going to do? Please review your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, but I have found out the answer of why this was happening. As while initializing the thread class in the parameter I should have provided this as to which run method should be run, so the initialization must have been something like this...

```
Thread t = new Thread(this)
```